# TFS 2013 raise conflict for every change

Tags: tfs, merge-conflict-resolution

I am trying to Merge a change set to parent branch, lately almost every change I make in the files is getting a conflict.

 In the image below you can see that I have made only a small change and it get consider as a conflict.

[image]

How can I change it so visual studio won't show me a conflict for every **space** I make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Diff and Merge tool in VS 2010 and earlier support command line options for ignoring whitespace, but current VS versions only support ignore trim whitespace. There is already a UserVoice at website: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/3063842-add-ignore-case-and-ignore-whitespace-options

As an alternate, you can replace diff/merge tool in VS to these support ignore whitespace, for example: [WinMerge](https://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/).

Answer (score 0):

You will always get a conflict when you make a change in two different branches to the same affected area(row or block of rows).

To stop getting conflicts, only make the change in one branch and then merge the changes to the other branch.

It might also be that you have not merged your files both ways for a while making you think that the files are identical in both branches. For this you need to merge: Branch1 -> Branch2 **and then** Branch2 -> Branch1.